# Optimising Quadratics on (general) unit spheres

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am aware that quadratic functions can be optimised over the unit Euclidean sphere. That is, there are algorithms for solving the following minimisation problem efficiently:
$$
\min_{\|x\|_{2} = 1} x^{\top}Ax + b^{\top}x
$$
Are there similar algorithms for different norms/spheres? For example, are there efficient algorithms for optimising over the $\ell_{1}$-sphere?
$$
\min_{\|x\|_{1}=1} x^{\top}Ax + b^{\top}x
$$

I assume this problem's connection to eigenvalues is destroyed once other norm constraints are considered? Or maybe there is some connection to the eigenvalues normalised with respect to the chosen norm?

EDIT: Let's consider a simpler example using the $\ell_{1}$-norm
$$
\min_{\|x\|_{1}=1} \frac{1}{2}x^{\top}Qx
$$
Using the Lagrangian, we have
$$
0 \in Qx + \lambda\partial(\|x\|_{1})
$$
**I am not sure how valid this approach is. What happens to the KKT conditions when subdifferentials are involved?**

But the subdifferential of the norm is given by
$$
\partial(\|x\|_{1}) = \{v \: : \: v^{\top}x = \|x\|_{1}, \|v\|_{\infty} \leq 1 \}
$$
and so we have to find $(x, v, \lambda)$ which solves the following system of equations:
$$
Qx + \lambda v = 0,\; v^{\top}x = \|x\|_{1}, \; \|v\|_{\infty} \leq \lambda, \; \|x\|_{1} = 1
$$
Thus we have
$$
Qx = -\lambda v
$$
Plugging this into the other inequalities (and using $\|x\|_{1} = 1$), we have:
$$
x^{\top}Qx = -\lambda, \: \|Qx\|_{\infty} \leq \lambda^{2}, \: \|x\|_{1} = 1
$$

In other words, we want to find the smallest $\lambda$ for which the above system of inequalities holds. I am unsure with how to proceed from here.

Comment: Why don't you just use lagrange multipliers? the constrain ist $x^T x = 1$

Comment: The constraint $x^{\top}x = 1$ corresponds to the norm constraint $\|x\|_{2} = 1$, however the constraint $\|x\|_{1}=1$ doesn't correspond to an inner product constraint like this. In the case of $\|x\|_{1}$, you could add the constraint $\max a^{\top}x = 1$ where the max is taken over all vectors $a$ whose entries are either 1 or -1, however I don't see how this constraint is any easier to handle.